# Copying header above using Javascript Regex Engine

Tags: regex

Suppose you have the following multi-line string:

```
seq 1 description 1
val 1
val 2
val 3
seq 2 description 2
val 4
val 5
val 6
```

I would like to copy the the content of the lines beginning with "seq" to all the lines below, which begin with "val".
I can do it just to the one line right below:

```
Regex: (^seq.*$)(\n)(val)
Substitution: $1$2$1 $3
Result:
seq 1 description 1
seq 1 description 1 val 1
val 2
val 3
seq 2 description 2
seq 2 description 2 val 4
val 5
val 6
```

But the result which I am looking for is the following:

```
seq 1 description 1 
seq 1 description 1 val 1
seq 1 description 1 val 2
seq 1 description 1 val 3
seq 2 description 2 
seq 2 description 2 val 4
seq 2 description 2 val 5
seq 2 description 2 val 6
```

Is it possible, only using Regex, or I do need a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookbehind, for example:

```js
let text = `
seq 1 description 1
val 1
val 2
val 3
seq 2 description 2
val 4
val 5
val 6
`;

text = text.replace(/(?<=^(seq.*)[\s\S]*?)^val/gm, '$1 $&');

console.log(text);
```

The `m` flag is used to turn on 'multiline' mode so `^` matches the start of a line and not just the start of the string. The `g` flag is used to match globally, i.e. as many times as possible.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aQ8yAc/1) for testing and further explanation.

Variation:

```js
text = text.replace(/(?<=^(seq[^\r\n]*).*?)(?=^val)/gms, '$1 ');
```